# Breaking down an array to access data

Tags: php

I have an array that's organised as follows:

```
options[0]['home']
options[0]['away']
options[1]['home']
options[1]['away']
```

It's created through a form, where input names are

```
name='options[0]['home']'
```

And so on.

My issue is that I can't seem to access the data, bizarre!

Should the following code get me access?

```
$_POST['options'][0]['home']
```

I've checked the contents and data is there as expected.

Thanks.

Comment: name='options[0]['home']' syntax error use name="options[0][home]"

Comment: why don't you just try that code?

Comment: I did try that code, what I'm getting at is that it won't work and it seems so basic so I've come on here to see if I'm missing something simple?

Comment: Please edit your question to show both the output of `var_dump($_POST);` and the actual code you are using the attempt to access the data

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error due to escaping '' in html.

Firstly learn some debugining `print_r($_POST)` to see what's there.

If you want to fix it then in html make

```
<input type="your_Type" name="options[0][home]">
```

or even

```
<input type="your_Type" name="options[home][]">
```

which seems better to me

Comment: I said in the question that I did check the array for contents and the data is there as expected. The $_POST[options] shows what I expect. So the question is am I trying to access it correctly?

Comment: if there is data in proper format then just access it what the problem? You should also include how is data formated. As I mentioned because of '' in name these chars can be escaped and in PHP it may not be treated as array

Comment: I can get as far in as print_r($_POST['options'][1] and it shows the two values as -1, as expected. Is this because the values are -1?

Comment: @Luke please just edit your question with print_r / var_dump output, rather than adding comments with little clues